# Getting array value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My debugging output below

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
         [re_text_field_id] => No posts to display
         [re_textarea_field_id] => boring jokes
         [re_image_field_id] => Array (
             [id] => 6
             [src] => http://localhost/project/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bg1.gif
        )
    ) [1] => Array (
         [re_text_field_id] => fuck it
         [re_textarea_field_id] => I feel dumb for asking, but how on earth would i go about using the repeatable fields in a way which outputs the fields needed
         [re_image_field_id] => Array (
             [id] => 4 [src] => http://localhost/project/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/bg-gradient1.png
         )
     )
 )
```

To get text field I used

```
$options = get_option('demo_options')
$slides = $options['re_']; 
foreach ($slides as $slide) {
echo $slide['re_textarea_field_id'];
}
```

But I am unable to get image path somewhat like this way

```
echo $slide['re_image _field_id'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, to retrive the path of the image. Need to add `['src']`

```
echo $slide['re_image_field_id']['src'];
```